# Show that a 10 × 10 board cannot be covered by non-overlapping T-tiles. T-tiles can be rotated.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

So I made a 10 x 10 board. I assumed that the board is a checker board and found that each tile would have three of the same color (either black or white) and 1 different color. However, I do not know what else to do with this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We let $a$ be the number of tiles covering three white squares and one black square and $b$ be the number of tiles covering one white square and three black squares. Then, we must have $3a+b = a+3b = 50$, since $50$ white squares and $50$ black squares must each be covered. This is only satisfied for $$a = b = \frac{25}{2}$$ which is not possible, assuming we have no way of splitting up tiles.

Comment: wait, wouldn't it be a = b = 25?

Comment: No. If $a = b = 25$, then $3a+b = a+3b = 100$, which would mean that $100$ white squares and $100$ black squares must be covered. There are only $50$ of each.

Comment: Wait but if you subtract a and b from both sides of 3a+b = a +3b you get 2a = 2b = 50. So how are we getting 25/2?

Comment: Something's wrong with your algebra. $3a+b = 50$ and $a+3b = 50$. Subtract the second from the first to get $2a-2b = 0$, or $a = b$. Then, plug in to get $4a = 4b = 50$, or $a = b = \frac{25}{2}$.

Comment: @user510 If you subtract a and b from 3a+b=a+3b=50 you get 2a=2b=50-a-b.

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

Assume an exact cover is possible.

How many $T$-tiles are needed?

Some will be majority white, others majority black.

But there must be the same number of each.